# Why when I tern flash light on my app go to stack?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, camera-flash

I work with `camera 2 API` to carry out my custom camera according [google sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) but with some additions that my app requires. All was good until I added permanent support of flash light

```
protected final void setAutoFlash(CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder) {
    if (isFlashSupported) {
        requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);
    }
}
```

I have checked it with `Meizu MX5` and `Samsung 5` it work properly, issue appears with `Samsung 6`... After I made the first capture, flash is flashing and app going to stack... without any stacktrace...

Could anyone assume what is the reason of the stack?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please clearify.....what do you mean with "app is going to stack" ? Background? Crash? Anything else?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I make a capture and then it is looks like capturing process finished, but nothing happen... it is just in suspend.. Looks like when app is doing a lot of work in main thread... I am clicking back button and main button and just in 3 -4 sec app is closing... and stacktrace is purging. As i said that it has appeared with `Samsung 6` and if I turn flash off it begin working properly ... I assume that issue with API camera2...